# Is Speech recognition the same thing as Google's paid API?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to use the speech recognition library for speech recognition. But I have one doubt: from this library, I can use Google. But Google proposes a paid speech recognition package. How could this be possible?

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def decodeSpeech(wavefile):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.WavFile(wavefile) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        try:
            print('Transcription GOOGLE: ' + r.recognize_google(
           audio, language='fr-FR', show_all=False))
        except LookupError:
            print('Cannot understand audio!')

        try:
            print('Transcription SPHINX: ' + r.recognize_sphinx(
            audio, language='fr-FR', show_all=False))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('Sphinx could not understand audio')
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print('Sphinx error: {0}'.format(str(e)))

WAVFILE = 'ma_maison_sylvie.wav'
decodeSpeech(WAVFILE)
```

Would line **r.recognize_google** the same as the Google paid API? It is *Google Speech Recognition* or *Google Cloud Speech API*?

Comment: It is not the same API, it is free but has pretty tight limits on usage.